# Limit points, subsets and topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau_{2}$ be topologies on a set $X$ with $\tau_{1} \subset \tau_{2}$.

How can I show that not every $\tau_{1}$-limit point is also a limit point of $\tau_{2}$?

Comment: Perhaps that you meant that $\tau_1\subset\tau_2$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, will fix now.

Answer (score 2):

For instance, take $\mathbb R$, let $\tau_1$ be the usual topology and let $\tau_2$ be the discrete topology. Then, $\tau_1\subset\tau_2$, $0$ is a $\tau_1$-limit point of $(0,1)$, but it is not a $\tau_2$-limit point. Indeed, every $\tau_1$-neighborhood $N$ of $0$ contains an interval of the type $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, for some $\varepsilon>0$. Therefore, $N\cap(0,1)\supset(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\cap(0,1)$, which is not empty. But $\{0\}$ is a $\tau_2$-neighborhood of $0$ (since it contains $0$ and it is an open set) which does not intersect $(0,1)$.

Comment: Could you please formulate your answer in terms of neighbourhoods?

Comment: @Dazzler95 Done.